# Example of a simply connected domain

Tags: complex-analysis, connectedness

I'm a bit stuck trying to think of an example of a simply connected domain $D$ whose complement $\mathbb{C} \setminus D$ is a disjoint union of infinitely many closed connected sets.

Could I be given a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a simply connected domain that contains infinitely many lines that all meet at a point (the origin, say).